# how to use find and where in single find in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm very new to loopback. i want to find records and it relative associated records. So i'm using include and where in find,but it not work properly.

this is my sample code:

```
Profile.find({{where: {and : [{xxx : req.param('xx')},{yyy : req.param('yyyy')}]}},{include: ['zzz']}}, function (err, instance) {
if(err){
    console.log('err');
     return ctx.res.send({notValid: "error"});
}
if(instance.length==0){
     return ctx.res.send({notValid: "error"});
}
    ctx.res.send({user: instance});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
Profile.find({where: {and : [{xxx : req.param('xxx')},{yyy : req.param('yyy')}]}, include: ['zzz']}, function (err, instance) {
    if(err){
        console.log('err');
         return ctx.res.send({notValid: "error"});
    }
    if(instance.length==0){
         return ctx.res.send({notValid: "error"});
    }
        ctx.res.send({user: instance});

});
```